# How to send post request with content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded with Karate?

Tags: oauth-2.0, karate, x-www-form-urlencoded

I have an endpoint that I use to get a token. I use content type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded. In body, I select "x-www-form-urlencoded" and provide 4 key values as seen in the picture. It works on postman, but I could not make it work in karate framework. I get connect time out error all the time. I tried to use form field for each key and one form field including all keys and values, but none of them worked. By the way, I did remove request section in the picture and try without request as well. it did not work, too.

Am I missing something? Thanks already and thanks for such a great tool for us!

[image]

Comment: Please share the error message as it would help in narrowing down the problem. Are there any proxy setup involved?  Please check if the following link helps: https://github.com/intuit/karate#managing-headers-ssl-timeouts-and-http-proxy

Comment: I hate these "it works in P*stman" comments >_< - anyway, quite likely you have a corporate proxy in the picture. do a search for other answers on SO, for e.g: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+postman+proxy

Answer (score 1):

Quite likely you have a corporate proxy in the picture. Do a search for other answers on SO, for e.g: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+postman+proxy

Here's how to set a proxy: https://github.com/intuit/karate#configure

```
karate.configure('proxy','http://myhost:80');
```

EDIT: for others landing here, besides the fact that an HTTP proxy may be in the picture - another place where Karate behaves a bit differently than Postman is that Karate [does not auto-send an `Accept` header by default](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/388#issuecomment-386845749).